# Getting playlist results on the Youtube API when specifying type:"video"

Tags: api, youtube

While developing a Google Chrome Extension I've stumbled upon a problem, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a Youtube Data API v3 bug.

So the problem is that I get playlist results even when I specify type:"video" on the "list" call.

To make sure it's not a problem with my code, I went to:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it

And I put the following on the fields:

```
part: snippet
channelId: UCy1Ms_5qBTawC-k7PVjHXKQ
maxResults: 50
q: Content Patch
type: video
```

And on the results i get:

```
  "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#playlist", // < Playlist item :\
    "playlistId": "PLB9225A9DA3422059"
   },
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"oLweQuB9Vh7wAB9a0AIHg_K-wsM/dR9GDZWu_nfsoaj5bdrHQ3Ng_GA\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-10-31T13:02:09.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCy1Ms_5qBTawC-k7PVjHXKQ",
    "title": "Content Patch",
    "description": "A daily gaming news show, which efficiently integrates opinionated commentary and also our viewers' feedback in a concise and to-the-point manner.",
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was most likely a bug in the API since it doesn't seem to happen anymore.